# How can I scrape "view" count of a comment with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape customer complaint data on a website. I can get the headline and date but cannot figure out how to get the view count.

This is the code to get the headline:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

complaints = []
time = []

for i in range(100):
  r = requests.get(f'https://www.sikayetvar.com/sikayetler?brand=bosch&page={i}')
  soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
  complaints += soup.find_all('h5', {"class":"card-title"})
  time += soup.find_all('span', {"class":"info-icn time-tooltip"})
```

The count of the complaints:

[image]

I try to get the number "479" with this code:

```
site = 'https://www.sikayetvar.com/sikayetler?brand=bosch'

r = requests.get(site)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
time = soup.find_all('span', {"class":"count"})
```

It returns:

```
print(time[0])
<span class="count">-</span>

print(time[0].text)
-
```

I just get "-" instead of "479". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or a way to get that number?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways how you can parse the names and their concerning counts from that site:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://collector.sikayetvar.com/complaints/view-count?'
url = 'https://www.sikayetvar.com/sikayetler?brand=bosch&page=1'

def get_count(data_id):
    r = requests.get(link,params={'complaints':f'{data_id}'})
    complaints = r.json()[0]['viewCount']
    return complaints

r = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select(".filter-cards > article.card"):
    name = item.select_one("h5.card-title > a").get_text(strip=True)
    complaints = get_count(item['data-id'])
    print(name,complaints)
```

Output are like:

```
Ürünleri Alamıyoruz Ve Bosch Hiçbir Sorumluluk Kabul Etmiyor 50
Bosch Buzdolabından Gelen Ses 508
Bosch Online Mağaza Sipariş Gecikmesi 225
Bosch Buzdolabı Soğutmuyor Alarm Ötüyor 499
Bosch Buzdolabı Sebze Ve Meyveliği Su Doluyor 589
Bosch Bulaşık Makinesi E09 Hatası 526
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are other elements with the class `count`. Try using the `{"class": "js-view-count"}` to get the elements. This will have a span in it which has the count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this also returns "-" instead of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Than count most probably is rendered by javascript to DOM and is not present in original html. Check html source  instead of inspector. I've checked the source of page 3 (`view-source:https://www.sikayetvar.com/sikayetler?brand=bosch&page=3`) and count is really just a `-` while the page shows 377.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58773630/5506730) might help you how to pre-render.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way we can scrape "count" values?

Comment: You can but you should wait the page render. Does the linked answer with selenium work for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Those views are shown by javascript and there is always a high chance of finding an XHR request related to that in Network Tab.
I found this site which returns those views in a JSON. https://collector.sikayetvar.com/complaints/view-count?complaints=14793971%2C14792534%2C14791327%2C14789107%2C14787731%2C14787333%2C14787160%2C14784871%2C14784832%2C14784823%2C14784535%2C14783714%2C14762547%2C14783312%2C14783264%2C14782822

These complaints are the id of each complaint separated by a comma and they can be found in the source of https://www.sikayetvar.com/sikayetler?brand=bosch we just have to replace the comma with '%2C' and make a full string of them
m

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125'}

brand = 'bosch'

site = f'https://www.sikayetvar.com/sikayetler?brand={brand}'
req = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
complaints = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'js-view-count'})
complaints = '%2C'.join(i['data-id'] for i in complaints)
print(complaints)

site = f'https://collector.sikayetvar.com/complaints/view-count?complaints={complaints}'
r = requests.get(site)
print(r.json())
```

Output:-

```
[{'id': 14793971, 'viewCount': 43, 'uniqueViewCount': 29}, {'id': 14792534,'viewCount': 501, 'uniqueViewCount': 263}, {'id': 14791327, 'viewCount': 218,'uniqueViewCount': 134}, {'id': 14789107, 'viewCount': 492, 'uniqueViewCount': 286},{'id': 14787731, 'viewCount': 581, 'uniqueViewCount': 342}, {'id': 14787333, 'viewCount':506, 'uniqueViewCount': 287}, {'id': 14787160, 'viewCount': 428,'uniqueViewCount': 249}, {'id': 14784871, 'viewCount': 25, 'uniqueViewCount': 16},{'id': 14784832, 'viewCount': 29, 'uniqueViewCount': 15}, {'id': 14784823, 'viewCount':20, 'uniqueViewCount': 8}, {'id': 14784535, 'viewCount': 99, 'uniqueViewCount': 57}, {'id':14783714, 'viewCount': 510, 'uniqueViewCount': 280}, {'id': 14762547, 'viewCount':139, 'uniqueViewCount': 85}, {'id': 14783312, 'viewCount': 142,'uniqueViewCount': 78}, {'id': 14783264, 'viewCount': 190, 'uniqueViewCount': 114},{'id': 14782822, 'viewCount': 216, 'uniqueViewCount': 120}]
```

The other way is to go in every complaint which will take a lot of time as well as the Website can block you if you keep scraping